# How configure the Error Queue in Jboss EAP7.0

Tags: jboss, queue, jms, activemq-artemis, jboss-eap-7

Planning to migrate the Weblogic JMS to Jboss EAP 7 - messaging-activemq.
In weblogic , We have a weblogic error queue configuration as below

```
 <delivery-failure-params>
      <error-destination>ErrorQueue</error-destination>
      <redelivery-limit>0</redelivery-limit>
      <expiration-policy>Redirect</expiration-policy>
    </delivery-failure-params>
```

Could you please let me know how to configure the ErrorQueue in Jboss EAP 7 and also I tried to configure DLQ but it will not work same as weblogic error-destination queue.

Thanks much